# How to interpret these command lines written in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

**A** is a matrix containing some matching points for a stereo vision system and the cameras' matrices. Regarding the problem, I know that I need to minimize a cost function relating the distance between a projected and a detected point.

Investigating some functions inside MATLAB I found this code that I suppose does this minimization because of the output I receive.

I'd like to understand, if possible, what *mathgician* is happening here:

```
    [~,~,V] = svd(A);
    X = V(:,end);
    X = X/X(end);
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What does matrix A look like? Have you checked the documentation for [svd](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[~,~,V] = svd(A);`

performs a [singular value decomposition](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) of the matrix A which produces three matrices as output. The first two of these are ignored (by assigning them to `~`, according to MATLAB convention) and the third is assigned to the variable `V`.

`X = V(:,end);`

assigns **the rightmost column** of matrix V to the variable `X` - the `:` means 'all', in this case 'all the rows'

`X = X/X(end);`

divides each element of `X` by the **last** element of `X` - or in other words, scales the vector X so that its last element is equal to 1.

Comment: nekomatic, thanks for the explanation regarding the matlab particularities. I need to investigate more about SVD and its applications, but your information will help me to dissect the code I've found. By the way, I found another post that may be useful for understanding SVD and Least Squares (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974193/why-does-svd-provide-the-least-squares-and-least-norm-solution-to-a-x-b)